# different way of calling a component

Tags: reactjs

i have a more theorical question

I have this component

```
class SearchTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { i18n } = this.props;


    const Results = (props) => {
        console.log('login props')
      if (this.props.versions.length) {
        return (
          this.props.versions.map(version => (
            <TableRow key={Math.random()} className={version.risk ? `label-${version.risk}` : 'label-none'}>
              <TableData data-title="foo">version.bar</TableData>
            </TableRow>))
        );
      }
      return (<div>hola</div>);
    };

    return (
      <Table className="andes-card">
        <TableHead>
          <TableHeader>foo</TableHeader>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            <Results />
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

but the Results is not getting executed (i am not getting the console log neither)

if I change my code to this

```
class SearchTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { i18n } = this.props;


    const Results = (props) => {
        console.log('login props')
      if (this.props.versions.length) {
        return (
          this.props.versions.map(version => (
            <TableRow key={Math.random()} className={version.risk ? `label-${version.risk}` : 'label-none'}>
              <TableData data-title="foo">version.bar</TableData>
            </TableRow>))
        );
      }
      return (<div>hola</div>);
    };

    return (
      <Table className="andes-card">
        <TableHead>
          <TableHeader>foo</TableHeader>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            {Results()}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

the Result component is getting rendered.

which is the difference? I used to use the  method and it was working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue** :- Result component  is defined inside render method. Thats why , you need to call it as a function .

**Solution** :- Define Result component as a member function of class then you can call it as
    `<this.Result/>` or define this function function outside of class SearchTable and call it as
    `<Result/>`.

It's a good practise to define  the functional component  outside of class, so that it could be called from another components as well.

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're trying to define a react component inside another. You can do this, but you need to make it a static property of the class.

```
 static Results = (props) => {...yourCode}
```

However, its best to just define it outside of the component class or in another file.

```
const Results = (props) => {...yourCode}
class SearchTable extends React.Component {...yourCode}
```

Then you just render it like a normal component `<Results />`